# Symfony2 custom theme for Grewar Captcha Bundle

Tags: symfony, themes, captcha

I use  [GregwarCaptchaBundle](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle) to generate captcha in Symfony 2.3.2. 
But I don't know how to custom theme for it, I don't want to use the default theme, it wasn't fit with my template. I can edit the default its theme, but I think it's not a good idea, because we can't reuse for many template.
Can somebody tell me how to do it. Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you find a way to put an image to the background other than update the CaptchaBuilder::build function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override like any other view in Symfony.
Create file `app/Resources/GregwarCaptchaBundle/views/captcha.html.twig`
And put down your changes following [this template](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/captcha.html.twig).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know what you mean, that works for me.